# Morals - Glitch in your system penalizes user undeservingly - do you compensate?

Tags: logic, ethics

I was wondering if it is the practice to compensate a user for a glitch in your system that penalized them. Namely, if Stack Exchange had a glitch which caused some of my awards to disappear, should they fix the glitch and add those awards back to my account? I would think so but I am getting a fairly large number of disagreements on MetaStackOverflow to my Question Here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167523/glitch-where-did-my-gold-badge-go#comment492656_167523

Comment: I've voted to close. As far as I can tell, this is _not_ a question about philosophy. Rather, it is a question asking us to evaluate the policies and (possible) glitches of the Stackexchange format. I have voted to close rather than asking for an edit because I do not see how this question could be turned into a question of philosophical interest.

Comment: @Dennis Do you think the moral thing to do or the ethical thing to do would be to compensate the user, or do you think it would be to just let them take the penalty for trying to use the site the way they intended.

Comment: IMO it's a straight-forward ethical question that happens to have an immediate example: "What's the right ('ethical') thing to do?" I could see closing as "obvious", because IMO *that* part is obvious. What's missing is a reality check of the ROI.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Is *your* behavior "ethical" right now? Is haranguing the SE landscape "ethical" considering what you're asking for (tens of dollars of time for a virtual trinket)?

Comment: @DaveNewton, thankyou for your reply. I'm not sure about the ethics behind my reaction but I do know that right now I feel like I have lost something I put a lot of effort into earning for a reason that seems unjustified to me. It feels similar to theft (even though that's NOT what it is). I don't think it's a matter of the value of what I lost without reason but rather the fact that I lost _something_ without reason.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I'd suggest maybe reconsidering your participation and what it means to be an SE citizen: would you *not* answer questions if you weren't rewarded with meaningless baubles? Do you *not* find the act of helping others intrinsically valuable? Do you feel that SE *owes* you anything other than a place to ask and answer questions? I'd mention that you've asked almost as many questions as you've answered--you've already *gotten* quite a bit from SO, it looks like; is it not enough?

Comment: @DaveNewton I answered questions when I first signed up without even knowing about the reward system, however they do have the reward system in place for a reason... and the reason is of course, because it works. It only works though if it continues to work, especially for long-time loyal clients. Sure they don't OWE me anything, we have no contracts... that's why this is an ethical question, not a question of legality.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw And I would say it's *obvious* that it works, and continues to do so, despite occasional issues--which are often blown so far out of proportion as to be disturbing. Hell, I asked to *not* get a badge when I was much closer to your relatively-low reputation level because I didn't think it was deserved--and that wasn't even a glitch, it was by *design*. Personally, I think the SE network is better served by people who think they get too *much* rather than too little.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'd like this to not become a personal debate on how you value my choices, mind-set, and motives. I can see that comment heading that way (not saying it will, but it might) so I'll end it with this. Thankyou.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw True, it's much easier to complain about the loss of... well, nothing, than to examine one's own behavior. Good luck!

Comment: ... Very shallow. I have examined my behavior, and it isn't nothing to me, I give expert advice in programming free-of-charge for months on end, this is why I place a high value on earning that badge... It is something I value, yes it's worth nothing in reality, but I think value is in the eye of the beholder. This is a philosophy site, not a condemnation site.

Comment: @DaveNewton (and Albert) Please take this to chat.

Comment: @Dennis I already flagged the post for comment cleanup (including mine, which I don't want to delete in isolation).

Comment: Closing question pending some clarification of the philosophical concern at issue.

Comment: Just in passing: this community isn't a court of last resort for SE; we're in no way arbiters of SE policy (or morality for that matter!) -- we're just philosophy students/teachers...

Comment: In my opinion, with any online services such as SO, you never actually "own" the badge. This is their ground, so they can do whatever the hell they want with the badge they have let you use, including taking them away for absolutely no reason at all. Morality or ethics does not come into play here since us users don't have any enforceable claim towards anything they owned. Nevertheless, a bug is a bug, and while they might try to fix and compensate glitches as a sign of good will, they are under no obligation - moral, legal, nor ethical - to do so.

Comment: @LieRyan I supposed in government we never actually own our currency either.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you link to *my* comment?

*I* didn't say they wouldn't give it back to you, I explained Animuson's comment regarding that *he* has never heard of an award being given manually.

You are avoiding the real-world cost/ROI equation for something that has zero intrinsic value.

Would it be *nice* to have your badge back? Sure. Is it *worth* it? Different question, and different people will answer it differently. We understand *your* answer. You'll have to wait for *their* answer, and no answer *is* an answer–but you're assuming short turnaround on something that isn't of critical importance.

Ethical actions have trade-offs: it sucks to kill, but would you to save a room of kids? Where do you draw the line between the action and the action's cost to you, and to others? Let's say it took an SE employee an hour to fix your badge issue: is your worthless gold badge worth $50? $100? $150? To who? To you? To SE?

Is it worth the cost of sounding like you're whining across multiple sites, posts, and comments? Who pays that cost? Not us–*you* do, in your public image, ephemeral as it is.

Comment: I think the real question would then be (if you are going to put such high values on the time of fixing something like this) is it worth this to them to fix a glitch that would happen to any user who created accounts so long ago that they were not associated because that system was not yet set up and they are now associating them. This is a glitch that could affect many users, especially their loyal users that have been with SE for years. I guess it boils down to what are they willing to do to provide the best user experience possible to their users and what are they not willing to do.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Fixing the glitch itself could cost hundreds or thousands of dollars; I'm speaking *only* of manually awarding a badge (assuming it's a simple matter of DB manipulation for which there is likely no UI). Yes, it *does* boil down to ROI, which is more or less what I've been saying, and Animuson's further comments explain more of the technical reasons.

Comment: Well if changing a database value (and maybe a minute of verification research) costs hardly anything would you agree that it would be worth it to keep a client of almost 2 years satisfied with your services, do you think the client (I) should be compensated (nothing additional, just my badges back) It took me almost 2 years to earn my gold badge, I have a job, I give expert advice in programming free-of-charge for months on end, this is why I place a high value on earning that badge... It is something I value, yes it's worth nothing in reality, but I think value is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Exactly: you think it's really important; I suspect you're in the minority precisely because it *isn't*. You think I *don't* have a job? You think I get *paid* to help other people on SO? Or am I not an expert? Come on: what on *earth* is making you think this is as important as you seem to think it is???